# How do I ungroup an sf dataframe with multiple sfc_POINT geometries to retain only 1 geometry column?

Tags: r, dplyr, spatial, r-sf

I have an sf dataframe (sfc_POINT geometry) made from 2 other sf dataframes (also sfc_POINT geometry). I want my final sf dataframe to have a single geometry column for a clean dataset for analysis, my current sf dataframe seems to have 6 groups and 6 geometry columns. I think the problem stems from using the dplyr::groupby() function in the 2 sf dataframes I used to derive my current sf dataframe. Realizing this, I went back and made sure to use the dplyr::ungroup() function at multiple steps, but the problem persists.

Below is my the geometry structure of my data, and code block where I attempted to ungroup any variables, remove the sf geometry, and recreate geometry.

"yo" is my current sfc_POINT dataframe. It is a tibble [3,063 × 3], S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame. Here is the output from the str(yo$geometry):

$ geometry :sfc_POINT of length 168465; first list element:  'XY' num [1:2] 256552 282745  - attr(*, "groups")= tibble [3,063 × 3] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)   ..$ Animal.ID: Factor w/ 112 levels "140040","140050",..: 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 ...   ..$ Date     : Date[1:3063], format: "2014-10-25" "2014-10-26" "2014-10-27" "2014-10-28" ... - attr(*, "sf_column")= chr "geometry" - attr(*, "agr")= Factor w/ 3 levels "constant","aggregate",..: NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...

```
yo <- yo %>% 
  #make sure data are ungrouped
  dplyr::ungroup() %>% 
  #create UTM coordinates from current sf geometry
  mutate(UTME = st_coordinates(yo)[,1],
         UTMN = st_coordinates(yo)[,2]) %>%
  #drop grouped geometry
  st_drop_geometry() %>% 
  #convert to standard dataframe to remove sfc_POINT format
  as.data.frame() %>% 
  #recreate one geometry column with coordinates I derived above
  st_as_sf(coords = c("UTME", "UTMN"), remove = T, crs = MontanaCRS)
```

I expected this to result in 1 geometry column of coordinates, but it is still putting out 6  POINT columns. I've worked a lot in the sf package and have not had this problem. I would appreciate any help or insight. Thanks a lot!

Comment: There is likely an easier way to achieve what you want, but it's hard to help without an actual example. Can you make a small example (one or two rows is fine) that demonstrates your issue, and also means we have some data to work with?

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. I am currently trying to form a reproducible example. When I filter down to only a few variables, the problem goes away. I've tried filter different variables to see if the problem is due to a specific variable to no avail. The problem may be related to a "Deprecated Proj.4 representation." I will post a reproducible example asap.

Comment: I fixed the issue. I believe the problem stemmed from the use of the scale() function when I was attempting to center and scale the covariates in my dataset. Without changing the vector to numeric with as.numeric() after I scaled them, the scale() function outputs a list vector. I believe the sf package then assigned each new list a separate geometry that was identical to the original geometry that resulted in 6 total geometry columns for my dataset. Thanks!